# If in reflection tokens everyone’s balance in a formula, then how is it deducted when the tokens are transferred

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

In reference to what another user told me

```
Simplified example

User A buys 10 tokens.

Current Reflection multiplier = 1.0

getBalance(user A) equals 10 * 1.0 = 10

Something happens which increases the reflection multiplier to 1.1

getBalance(user A) equals 10 * 1.1 = 11 The users balance changes without any transfer transactions having to be done.
```

What I'm trying to understand is if everyone's balance is a formula instead of being a fixed value then how would this work if someone sends some of their tokens out

[Reflect.Finance: RFI Token | Address 0xa1afffe3f4d611d252010e3eaf6f4d77088b0cd7 | Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa1afffe3f4d611d252010e3eaf6f4d77088b0cd7#code)

Comment: https://reflect-contract-doc.netlify.app/ This paper sums up pretty well how the math behind reflection tokens work